# Deploying app to Google App Engine (python)

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I'm new to this and trying to deploy a first app to the app engine. However, when i try to i get this message:
"This application does not exist (app_id=u'udacity')."
I fear it might have to do with the app.yaml file so i'll just leave here what i have there:

application: udacity
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up a Google Cloud Project for your application?  This is where the app_id is created.  If you haven't set up a project, you need to.

If you have set up a project, it seems like you might be using the wrong application id.  Head over to the [dashboard page of the Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).  From there, you should see your app_id listed in the top left corner.  Make sure to use this id when deploying.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. create the project in your google app engine account by specifiying the 
   Application identifier and title(say you have given your application identifier 
   is=helloworld)
2. Go to the google app engine launcher and match your project name in the 
   app.yaml 
   with the name identifier you created in your google app engine account and then deploy it.